# Custom error page not displaying

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm doing a website using the php framework symfony and twig. I want to display a custom page for errors like 404 or 500. I saw [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html) how to do the custom page, I have the error.html.twig in `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error.html.twig` but it does not seem to be called, I'm also using the

```
_errors:
    resource: "@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml"
    prefix:   /_error
```

in `routing_dev.yaml` and neither in the dev nor on the live site you can see the custom or the default error page.

I've looked everywhere to find how does this page gets called but I cannot find anything so if you know how to do it, or where can I find documents about this I would be really grateful.

--I know this question mmay be seen as too broad, but I really can't find anything on google about this, any help will be good--

Comment: have you cleared cache and tried it?

Answer (score 0):

The error.html.twig will be shown in production on any HTTP error (e.g. 401/ 404/ 500 etc); try it by visiting `/made-up-path` on your host.

You can't check this catch all error.html.twig directly in dev AFAIK, but you can check for custom 404 error pages. What I have done is rename `error.html.twig` to `error404.html.twig` and then test this in the dev environment using `/app_dev.php/_error/404.html`. [as described here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#testing-error-pages-during-development). When it works rename back to `error.html.twig`.

Remember to clear cache after any changes you expect to see in prod environment.

It's a shame you can't test the catch-all `error.html.twig`.

Comment: I did try it on the host but it  sends me to a broken page, no error page. And also it displays `Fatal error: Call to a member function getDisplayname() on null in...` and this is something I get every time with a wrong path.

Comment: Do you call `->getDisplayname()` in your `error.html.twig` / `error404.html.twig`? is that the error you get when viewing in `/app_dev.php/_error/404.html`?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with it. Almost every time when there is a bug in my app I get the same error.

Comment: This is the problem you are having ... what's creating it is the question. Could be a service, another bundle, a parent class/template. You'll need to trace this error, where it's being called etc. What's the full error?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getDisplayname() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\src\Company\Bundle\TheBundle\Controller\Norm‌​alUserController.php on line 20, but I looked it up, and everything seems to be right. :/... As you said it is declared as a service  `controller.normaluser:
            class: Company\Bundle\TheBundle\Controller\NormalUserController`

Comment: Whatever variable is calling the `getDisplayname()` method is null on line 20 of `Norm‌​alUserCont‌​roller.php`, that's your problem that need resolving.

Comment: It's not even callin that method :/ this is the line 20, `$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();`

Answer (score 0):

Seems you little bit misunderstood the doc

1. You can customize your error page for production env, but when you call your local front controller as app_dev.php you won't see that custom page. So call app.php instead
2. about routing_dev.yaml

> With this route added, you can use URLs like
>
> http://localhost/app_dev.php/_error/{statusCode}
>   http://localhost/app_dev.php/_error/{statusCode}.{format}
>
> to preview the error page for a given status code as HTML or for a
>   given status code and format.

as you can see it will just create additional links to preview the custom pages directly by visiting that links. So if you will call http://localhost/app_dev.php/_error/404.html you will see the preview of that page that will appear on production for "not found"

Comment: Yes I can preview the site doing that, and going to the direct path. But what I want to know is how does it gets displayed with a wrong path, because if I enter a wrong path it sends me to a broken page, no error page. And also it displays `Fatal error: Call to a member function getDisplayname() on null in...`

Comment: I suppose you can haw some routing configured that match your wrong pass to some route of your controllers. "Call to a member function getDisplayname() on null in...", the key of answer is hidden behind ...

Comment: I saw the method going to the route on the controller, but there is no routing configured there and that method has nothing to do with it. Almost every time when there is a bug in my app I get the same error.

Comment: then you need to find out who catches that error and add some logic to hadle it. ie throw 404 exception is conent is not found by pattern